# AWS Lambda to delete objects older than 7 days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have files uploaded to S3 on a daily basis and I want to have a scheduled Lambda that checks the upload date of the file and deletes any files older then 7 days.  I tried using S3 Object Lifecycle but that deletes all of my directory structure as well.

I have this working on a local server with a crontab that runs the following.

```
@daily find /share/sftp -type f -iname '*' -mtime +7 -delete
```

Does anyone have example code for this use case on AWS Lambda?  Google hasn't come up with any relevant results.

Comment: How many total S3 objects are we talking?  If you've got 1000 it's not too bad. If you've got many millions then this is going to be an expensive operation.  How about a Lambda trigger every time a file is created that puts that into a database of some sort.  Then a daily cloudwatch event to run a Lambda to clean up S3 and the database?

Comment: It would be 10s of files.  The database is an interesting idea but I think it would be cleaner if it could be based on the upload date or last modified date.

Answer (score 0):

Does it really matter if the folder-structure is deleted? If the question is of ACL, then permissions can be given to the user to create a folder( if not existing ) within a specific parent-folder of choice. The point here is, life-cycle is the ideal way to expire objects in S3.

Comment: The folder structure matters because users upload files into certain directories and expect the directory tree to exist.  The user that is uploading files should not have to recreate the directory tree every day when they upload a file.  I could possibly create a new lifecycle rule for every subdirectory but from my testing, this still deletes parts of the directory tree.

Comment: @MitchellMeffert Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. For example, a file can be uploaded with a key of `invoices/january.txt` and it will work, even if the `invoices` directory does not exist. It will magically 'appear'. How are your users uploading the files?

Comment: We are using Transfer Family and the users are uploading via SFTP.  I tried setting up a lifecycle rule with the prefix of `Client1/Mailings/` which ended up removing `Mailings` as well as the files contained in `Mailings`. I would like the lifecycle rule to leave `Mailings` and only remove the files under it.  For example `Client1/Mailings/List.xlsx` should be removed.